# Android Phonegap - detect home button?

Tags: android, cordova

I have the following script that monitors the android back button actions -

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true); 


function backKeyDown() { 


if($.mobile.activePage.is('#homepage')){
  setTimeout( function() {navigator.app.exitApp();}, 100 );

}
else {
    setTimeout( function() {$.mobile.changePage("#homepage");}, 100 );

}
```

}

I would like to also close the app when the physical home button is pressed - does anyone know how to detect this?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that but you can kill your app in `onPause()` method instead see more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

**EDIT:**

Doing that in onPause will get your app killed whenever the user leaves the activity, I am not sure if there is a way to do what you want in android though, also is not recommended!

You can create some complex broadcast messaging system that sends messages from your activities to the application instance at a given interval of time and if you don't get any message in the application instance for x seconds then you know that the app is in background..

You can do that using a base activity class that sends messages at x seconds until onPause is called and extend that activity in all the other activities that you use so you can have this behaviour.

This is for sure not the best option that is out there and will consume battery life depending on the implementation so you have to be really sure that you need this before implementing such thing.

Comment: This will also be triggered when the user switch his screen off

Answer (score 0):

Capturing the Hardware's `Home` key event is bad approach and Android will never allow you to do that. and for closing the app, android framework will automatically send your app to background so you don't need to care about closing your app on `Home` button pressed event.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Adil.. but if you really want to or need to exit your app, adding the same listener/function for PhoneGap's "pause" event would probably do the trick.