# How can i detect home pressed event in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to close the app when the physical home button is pressed - does anyone know how to detect this?

.I try onPause event, but i have Social Shearing option in my application. After clicking dedicated button for shearing, Social Activity starts and my application going to close

Comment: you can't handle the home button press 
but you can simply close the app using "onPause" event that occurs when your activity pause after clicking the home button

Comment: Yes i do, but i have Social Shearing option in my application. After clicking dedicated button for shearing, Social Activity  starts  and my application going to close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Phonegap - detect home button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746518/android-phonegap-detect-home-button)

Comment: use something like the following to detect the recent task and check if it's the home screen
`ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);`

`ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo recentTaskInfo = activityManager.getRecentTasks(1, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED).get(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searches, I did't find answer. There is no any event in phonegap for Home button press.

Answer (score 0):

Home button work as a resume in android, you can add listener and implement it:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function(){
 //handle event here
 }, true);
```